# Kendo datasource parse Json as undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I tried to binding remote DataSource for my Kendo DropDownList, but the Kendo Datasource could parse the json response correctly. The result turns out to be "undefined" and recognize every single charachter in the data as a selection. I have no idea where the bug is, please help me!

Responce from controllor:

> "[{"CODE_ID":"A","CODE_NAME":"Free"},{"CODE_ID":"B","CODE_NAME":"Borrowed"},{"CODE_ID":"U","CODE_NAME":"Unable"},{"CODE_ID":"C","CODE_NAME":"To be Borrowed"}]"

[HTML Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgh53.png)

Front-end js code for Kendo DropDownList

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_category").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "CODE_NAME",
        dataValueField: "CODE_ID",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/BookData/GetDataList",
                    data: { name: "category" },
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
        },
    });
}
```

BookDataControllor

```
[HttpGet()]
public JsonResult GetDatalist(string name)
{
    string result;
    try
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "category":
                result = codeService.GetDataList("CODE_ID, CODE_NAME",
                "BOOK_CODE", "CODE_TYPE = 'BOOK_STATUS'");
                break;
            default:
                return Json(false);
         }
         return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(false);
    }
}
```

back-end class CodeService

```cs
private DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.GetDBConnectionString()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
    }

    return dt;
}

public string GetDataList(string col, string src, string cond)
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable(string.Format(@"SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2}",
                                    col, src, cond).ToUpper());
    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: did you try it in camel case?
`dataTextField: "category_Name",`
`dataValueField: "category_ID"`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that. I change them into right names, but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `CODE_ID` and `CODE_NAME` in your controller, but the values you're referencing on the front-end are `Category_Name` and `Category_ID`. Change them to reference the correct column names:

```js
$('#search_category').kendoDropDownList({
  dataTextField: 'CODE_NAME',
  dataValueField: 'CODE_ID',
  dataSource: {
    transport: {
      read: {
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/BookData/GetDataList',
        data: { name: 'category' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad. I fixed it. 
Unfortunately, I still encounter the same problem after corrtecting the name.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste a truncated response from your network tab?

Comment: return string from GetDataList: "[{\"CODE_ID\":\"A\",\"CODE_NAME\":\"Free\"},{\"CODE_ID\":\"B\",\"CODE_NAME\":\"Borrowed\"},{\"CODE_ID\":\"U\",\"CODE_NAME\":\"Unable\"},{\"CODE_ID\":\"C\",\"CODE_NAME\":\"To be Borrowed\"}]"

Comment: and the responce: [{"CODE_ID":"A","CODE_NAME":"Free"},{"CODE_ID":"B","CODE_NAME":"Borrowed"},{"CODE_ID":"U","CODE_NAME":"Unable"},{"CODE_ID":"C","CODE_NAME":"To be Borrowed"}]

Comment: @R.Huang - I am unable to replicate your issue with that JSON. See this example: https://dojo.telerik.com/OmoSUJeN

Comment: Thanks! I'll checkout the document!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even returning your data with `Json(result)` as `JsonResult`, the response content could be a string, which the DataSource is not handling the right way.

Try enrusing that it will be json with `parse` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_category").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "CODE_NAME",
        dataValueField: "CODE_ID",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/BookData/GetDataList",
                    data: { name: "category" },
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                parse: function(data) {
                    // Here you can check what 'data' really is
                    console.log(data);
                    return JSON.parse(data);
                }
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot!